# ESRI shape files

Tags: graphics, import, data-format

[ESRI shape files (shp)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile): importing the polygon data can yield a very large list.
It is computationally intensive rendering the polygon. I have been trying to convert to `GraphicsComplex` by extracting all the vertices, indexing them and then specifying the polygon by the vertex index.

However, the computational effort of removing duplicates (shared borders) seems to be computationally worse than the original issue (for the large input size of the list of vertices).

Can someone advise me if there is a better way to work with these files?

[I am able to use them but not efficiently.](http://ubpdqnmathematica.wordpress.com/2012/05/25/a-matter-of-shape/)

Comment: To clarify, it is the rendering of the Graphics that you find slow, correct?  Does this effect all (large) files some more than others?

Comment: I have the same problem. I was also thinking about using GraphicsComplex and have some ideas about how to remove the duplicates but I haven't tried these yet.

Comment: Do you use single polygons `Polygon[pts]` or the multi-primitive syntax `Polygon[{pts1,pts2}]`? Using the latter you can speed up rendering quite a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your needs it may be helpful to know that a significant amount of time is spent converting a `Graphics` expression to output Box forms.  Example:

```
graphics = Import["http://exampledata.wolfram.com/usamap.zip", "Graphics"];

Timing[cell = Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@graphics, "Output"];]
```

> {1.466, Null}

It is now significantly faster to print this pre-converted `Cell` expression than it is to print `graphics`:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, 
  EvaluationCompletionAction -> "ShowTiming"]

CellPrint[cell] (* 0.52 second *)

graphics  (* 1.75 seconds *)
```

---

Although I doubt it is robust and options are likely to be fragile, at least with version 7 one may leverage that fact in this particular case by doing a similar `Graphics` to `GraphicsBox` conversion manually, bypassing the internal `ToBoxes` routine:

```
Cell[BoxData[
   graphics /. {Graphics -> GraphicsBox, Line -> LineBox, Polygon -> PolygonBox}
  ], "Output"] // CellPrint  (* 0.52 second *)
```

[Credit to Szabolcs for this trick.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3365276#3365276)